Pandas Remove First Character From Column if Conditions Are Met
I have a Series that contains a phone # extension (in the format of x1234). However our system has a limit of 5 characters.
How do I remove the x (first character) if the string length is 6?
Here is my code:
mask1 = df['EXT'].str.startswith('x')
mask2 = df['EXT'].str.len() == 6
df[(mask1 & mask2)]['EXT'] # Apply both masks to only filter for these conditions and return the EXT

How do I set the value just for these results to remove the first character?

You could use string slicing (or str.slice) to cut off the first character when the extension matches your conditions. For example:
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'EXT' : ['x1234', 'x12345', '4555', 'x9902', '12345', 'x98765'] })
mask1 = df['EXT'].str.startswith('x')
mask2 = df['EXT'].str.len() == 6

df.loc[mask1 & mask2, 'EXT'] = df['EXT'].str[1:]
# or more long-winded
# df.loc[mask1 & mask2, 'EXT'] = df['EXT'].str.slice(1)

print(df)

Output:
     EXT
0  x1234
1  12345
2   4555
3  x9902
4  12345
5  98765


You could combine the two conditions in a single call to str.replace:
df['EXT'] = df['EXT'].str.replace(r'x(.{5,})', r'\1', regex=True)

Example (output as "EXT2" for clarity):
      EXT    EXT2
0   x1234   x1234
1  x12345   12345
2  123456  123456

regex demo

I did consider using regex... I suspect masking and slicing would be faster just because no regex :)

I think we can keep first 5 characters from the right hand side. If this is correct, without other condition and equivalent to your need, then:
df['new'] = df['EXT'].apply(lambda x: x[-5:] if len(x) > 5 else x)


But I want to filter where the first character is x also

@Bijan can you have extensions without x that are longer than 5? If not then this should work fine (I'd use df['EXT'] = df['EXT'].str[-5:] however). If you can, then how should those extensions be handled?
